# Undefined control sequence: new defined math in caption

Tags: captions, undefined

When I compile document with this code:

```
\documentclass[final,3p,times]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, amsfonts, amsthm,latexsym}


\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{mathtools} \usepackage[normalem]{ulem} \usepackage{scalerel}

\newcommand{\Ro}{\mathrel{\overset{0}{\sim}}}

\title{test}

\date{March 2020}


\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\maketitle \section{test.\ $\Ro$}


\end{document}
```

I get that the compiler is having trouble understanding a command I have defined. Check whether the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using `\usepackage{...}`.

It does not work on overleaf.com and my PC, however in my laptop with Ubuntu it does not produce any error.

Could anyone tell me how to avoid or fix this?

---

### update:

I tried to take the suggestion of changing the ordering of how `amssymb` and `amsmath` are loaded; it works.

```
\documentclass[3p,times]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,amsmath}
\newcommand{\Ro}{\mathrel{\overset{0}{\sim}}}
\begin{document}
    \section{test.\ $\Ro$}

    \begin{proof}
        asfaag
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

However, if I add all my packages, the problem returns.

```
\documentclass[3p,times]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithmic,algorithm}
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hfill$\rhd∗$\textit{#1}}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\newcommand{\Ro}{\mathrel{\overset{0}{\sim}}}
\begin{document}
    \section{test.\ $\Ro$}

    \begin{proof}
        asfaag
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: (a) No need to load the `amsfonts` package explicitly (twice, no less!) since the package is loaded automatically by the `amssymb` package. (b) No need to load `latexsym` at all, since it's been superseded (more than 25 years ago, by the way) by the `amssymb`/`amsfonts` pair of packages.

Comment: Thanks for telling

Answer (score 5):

It's quite a strange interaction with `scalerel`. I can reproduce the behavior with a simpler example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\newcommand{\Ro}{\mathrel{\overset{0}{\sim}}}

\begin{document}

\section{test.\ $\Ro$}

\end{document}
```

The issue disappears when `scalerel` is removed.

Solution: use

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Ro}{\overset{0}{\sim}}
```

(I removed `\mathrel` because it's not necessary, since `\sim` is a relation symbol and `\overset` is able to guess it correctly).

Answer (score 2):

Many thanks for producing a full MWE (minimum working example). I was immediately able to reproduce the error on a pre-release version of MacTeX2020. Specifically, I got the following sequence of messages:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@tempa ->\catcode `\<
                      12\relax \catcode `\>12\relax \catcode `\=12\relax 
l.22 \section{test.\ $\Ro$}

? r
OK, entering \nonstopmode...
! Undefined control sequence.
\@tempa ->\catcode `\<
                      12\relax \catcode `\>12\relax \catcode `\=12\relax 
l.22 \section{test.\ $\Ro$}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

---

I'm not sure *why* the following solution works, but here goes: Load the `amssymb` package *before*, not after, the `amsmath` package.

Reducing your code to the bare essentials, i.e. to

```
\documentclass[3p,times]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\newcommand{\Ro}{\mathrel{\overset{0}{\sim}}}
\begin{document}
\section{test.\ $\Ro$}
\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

without any error or warning messages. What makes the difference is that `amssymb` is loaded before rather than after `amsmath`.

Comment: thanks, somehow if i add all of my packages, it fails again.

Comment: @ginger - Your initial posting didn't mention the fact that your real document loads the `scalerel` package. Would you like me to delete my answer as it doesn't appear to address the real document's issue?

Comment: I think it is good if you keep it. Since this is also a way to fix it, if there is no scalerel. I did not know that this causes the problem.